# Can the Windows 8.1 Preview be upgraded to the final release?

Tags: windows-8.1-preview

I would like to try out the [Windows 8.1 Preview](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/preview) by getting the update through the Store on my current Windows 8 installation. My only concern is that I can't find any information in the [FAQ](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/preview-faq) about an upgrade path to the final version.

It states that Windows RT 8.1 Preview will be upgradable to Windows RT 8.1, but how about x86 versions?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is no longer relevant

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The same rules apply.  If you upgrade `Windows 8` to `Windows 8.1 Preview` you will have to reinstall all your desktop and `Windows Store` applications once you upgrade the `Windows 8.1 Preview` to `Windows 8.1 RTM`.  Every single one of those FAQ applies to both `Windows RT` and `Windows 8`.

The important information is the following statement.

> When you install subsequent editions of Windows 8.1 you'll be able to
>   keep your personal files, but you'll need to reinstall your apps.

If upgrade to Windows 8.1 by using the `Windows Store` update or you use a Windows 8.1 RTM installation media you will keep all your personal files, settings, and installed applications.  Any `Windows Store` applications in either case will be downloaded again and be updated as required.

Comment: There it is, thanks. The "you'll need to reinstall your apps" part is confusing. I guess you take apps to also mean desktop programs.

Comment: I guess that is a dealbreaker. I wouldn't mind reintsalling Windows Store apps, but the desktop ones would be too big of a hassle.

Comment: Good option, I'll keep it in mind.

Comment: Actually, I don't think Ramhound's suggestion is going to work. I think the two OSes may be too different.

Comment: I was talking about the refresh image comment.

Comment: I think the naming may be misleading, being called 8.1, since it is a new kernel. It seems as different as Server 2008 and 2008 R2.

Comment: @Ramhounud Right, that is the point I want to make. I don't think there is a going back when we see a kernel version change.

Comment: I agree, I just wanted to warn others who might feel like trying the preview before then, with the hopes of rolling back for the RTM update.

Comment: If you are going to downvote this question it might help to know the reason you are doing so otherwise I cannot improve this answer.  **This comment is not directed towards Louis.**

Comment: The serial downvoting of my highly accepted answers is getting a ridiculous.  If you have a problem with something I have said, come talk to me in chat, don't serial downvote me on `Stackoverflow` and `Superuser` **its just going to get reversed anyways.**

Answer (score 2):

There exists a possibility to upgrade from preview to final version of windows 8. This way is not supported by microsoft. So you should backup you data first, if anything went wrong.

The trick is to modify the version number of the installer its self. A full tutorial or possible tool can be found in this [forum](http://forums.mydigitallife.info/threads/47611-Complete-Upgrade-from-Windows-8-1-Preview-to-Windows-8-1-RTM-without-loosing-files).